# What is the proper name for 'audio codec' ?

Tags: audio, terminology

Is there any formal name for audio codecs? My lecturer said today that audio codec is a jargon and I should not use these words in my diploma, unfortunately she did not tell me if there is a proper name. I was surprised because it is so widely used in datasheets.

Comment: [chuckle] [Codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) stands for "coder-decoder" or "compressor-decompressor".  Check if your lecturer approves.

Comment: If engineers can get paid for developing or integrating "audio codecs", it's okay to get a diploma while using the term.

Comment: What else is going on the diploma?

Comment: Is "[diploma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma)" the right word here? Do you mean "[thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis)"?

Comment: "What else is going on the diploma? " I find this question a little confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Codec *is* the proper name. It is also jargon in that laypersons do not know what it properly means.

[Codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec):

> a device or program that compresses data to enable faster transmission and decompresses received data.

[Jargon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jargon):

> special words or expressions that are used by a particular profession or group and are difficult for others to understand

If you want to avoid the jargon, either explain what a codec is or simply refer to it by its definition.

Comment: "Codec" does not necessarily mean compression and decompression. It could be any form of transcoding, including things like u-law to A-law conversion, or in some cases, even ADC and DAC -- in fact, the word is often used to denote nothing more than a single chip ADC/DAC combo.

Comment: @DaveTweed The definition I gave comes from a "define codec" Google search. It is, I believe, the most common use of the word. Though I agree not the only use.

Comment: Ah, you youngsters! The word has been in common use in the telecom industry for more that 40 years, far longer than the existence of Google! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

So, does she disapprove of "modem" or "pixel"?

It's exactly the same kind of [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) word as modem (modulator-demodulator -> modem and encoder-decoder -> codec). Or pixel (picture element -> pixel).

I agree with Samuel, as jargon, you can define it once in your paper, and thenceforth use the term throughout the paper. Of course it doesn't pay to unduly tick off the person that's marking you, so you should make some such accommodation.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'lecturer' might be pressing you to be a bit more specific because the term 'codec' has become a bit broad of late.  Is it a 'hardware codec'... or just an app in your phone?

I believe 'codec' actually began as shorthand or jargon to quickly reference a specific process for coding/decoding audio. Was it... Sony? that did this first?   That was some years ago.  And, if I remember correctly it didn't take too long for several variants to begin appearing in the commercial broadcast and recording industries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs gives you an idea, and it seems this list just keeps growing.

One thing you must do is be specific.  So - yes.  There is / are SEVERAL formal names for audio codecs.   To which are you referring, in what circumstance, and why?

Once you start thinking that way, you probably won't refer to your item as a codec anymore.

Comment: It is a hardware codec. I refer to it as IC on board.

Comment: *Which* IC? Looking at it's datasheet should give an idea which type of "codec" it is today. One would think "codec" means audio-to-MP3 or similar, but like @DaveTweed says, don't be surprised if you only see ADCs and DACs in it. (Leaving any real "compression" up to the host processor.)